# ISS Express 10, HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found (Incorrect Physical Path)

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2022

When running/debugging my project (web based MVC ASP.NET) on visual studios 2022 with IIS Express, I run into this error:
[image of error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4vLs.png)

The issue that arises is that the **physical path** is not directed to my repos folder (C:\Users\DillonJackson\source\repos\projectname) it directed to a random empty folder that it made so it obviously can't find anything.

/home is handled and will send me to a login screen.
The project runs just fine on my old windows 10 laptop, I just upgraded to a new windows 11 laptop.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling Visual Studios
- Reinstalling ISS Express 10.0
- Modifying the applicationhost.config
  [applicationhost.config modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/depec.png)

Comment: What kind of solution? If none of your code handles `/home`, no doubt 404.0 is expected. Learn how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow and always provide enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Locating the hidden `.vs` folder in my projects root folder in file explorer
2. Locate `applicationhost.config` and open it in any editor
3. Going to `<sites>` and commenting out any `<site>` that was unneeded and manually changing the physical path of the `<site>` that was used to the correct file path.

   Edited `applicationhost.config` file:

   [image: image of the edited applicationhost.config file]

Originally, I had tried modifying the `applicationhost.config` for the general IIS Express, not the one built for the project.

Comment: Manual editing on the file is really not recommended, as newer VS versions like 2022 have built-in mechanism to keep it in sync with your project file. If you only edit at one place, that sync mechanism might break and lead to other issues.